# Jquery - On click change append parameter only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

With present code, data-endpoint path changing as

```
data.15435.json?parameter=test
data.13588.json?parameter=test?parameter=test
data.15435.json?parameter=test?parameter=test?parameter=test
```

On each change, parameter is appending. But, need to include this parameter only once.

```js
$('a.dropdown-item').on('click', function(){
    let getDataKey = $(this).attr('data-key');
    let getEndPoint = $('.detail.component').attr('data-endpoint');
    var getEndPointVal = getEndPoint.replace(/[.0-9]*\.json/, '.' + getDataKey + '.json');
    var getEndPointValParam = getEndPointVal + '?parameter=test';
    var getJsonUrl = $('.detail.component').attr('data-endpoint', getEndPointValParam);
    let getNewDataKey = getJsonUrl;

    console.log(getJsonUrl)
}
```

```html
<div class="detail component" data-endpoint="detail.json">
..
</div>


<div class="dropdown start-date">
 <button id="startdate" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">List 1</button> 
 <div class="dropdown-menu">
  <a type="button" data-key="15435" class="dropdown-item">List 1</a>
  <a type="button" data-key="13588" class="dropdown-item">List 2</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to parse `url` with `regex` and check if there are any params after `?` sign. that will gave the ability to append once.

Comment: Why are you saving the constructed endpoint value? It would be simpler just to construct it on the fly each time, then you won't run into this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way how i can see, is to set the `data-endpoint` to be a permanent or constant. Try this:

```js
let getEndPoint = $('.detail.component').attr('data-endpoint');

$('a.dropdown-item').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let getDataKey = $(this).data('key');
    var array = getEndPoint.split('.'); //now it is an array
    var getEndPointVal = array[0] + '.' + getDataKey + '.' + array[1];
    var getEndPointValParam = getEndPointVal + '?parameter=test';
    $('.detail.component').data('endpoint', getEndPointValParam);
    var getJsonUrl = $('.detail.component').data('endpoint');

    console.log(getJsonUrl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="detail component" data-endpoint="detail.json">
</div>


<a href="#" data-key="15435" class="dropdown-item">List 1</a>
<a href="#" data-key="13588" class="dropdown-item">List 2</a>
```